# How to execute wait time on a seperate thread to stop UI from freezing

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, while-loop, wait

I'm trying to increment the floor, and every time the status of the floor should change and show on the floor slowly increasing to the desired floor. But the floor just waits then jumps straight to he desired floor without me seeing it gradually increment. I'm assuming it's because the UI is frozen every time it hits sleep and therefore I don't see the gradual incrementing.

So how do I execute the wait on another thread (if thats even the problem) to stop the UI from not freezing?

Here's my code:

```
        while (floor > elevator.currentFloor)
        {
            elevator.currentFloor++;
            changeStatus(elevator);
            currentFloorLbl.Text = "Current Floor: " + elevator.currentFloor;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
```

Comment: You need to run your entire while loop on a different thread, possibly using a BackgroundWorker or using Task.Factory.StartNew(...).

Comment: @failedprogramming Failed.

Comment: Can I have an example please?

Comment: Here's a tutorial that shows using BackgroundWorker to update a label - should be similar to what you are trying achieve. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Win Forms, move your code into a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).  If not, use the [appropriate .NET timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx).

Comment: David,  good solution; however, I would provide him with an example.

Comment: This is going to be overcomplicated for the OP given that the `CurrentFloorLbl` is likely a UI element. Stick to single threaded, use .net 4.5

Comment: The MSDN article for the System.Windows.Forms.Timer had a good example.

Comment: @Aron - the System.Windows.Forms.Timer is called back on the UI thread, therefore it is permissible to update the UI.

Comment: @DavidChing I said it was overly complicated, not impossible. We should be teaching current methods here. Otherwise you should suggest, "new up a thread, run a loop, marshal a signal back to the UI thread using Form.BeginInvoke, run update...blah blah blah"...

Comment: @Aron - using BeginInvoke is not needed, just handling a timer callback is sufficient.  If you are looking for an acknowledgement that your one line answer using 'await' is simpler... well it is certainly less typing, but timers are easier to understand than tasks and 'await'.

Answer (score 1):

```
    while (floor > elevator.currentFloor)
    {
        elevator.currentFloor++;
        changeStatus(elevator);
        currentFloorLbl.Text = "Current Floor: " + elevator.currentFloor;
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
```

As you can see, we are using `await Task.Delay(500)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(500)`. These both achieve the same thing, that is stops execution of your code for 500ms.

The difference is that `Thread.Sleep(500)` is what we call a blocking call. It tells your thread (UI thread, the thread that draws on your screen) to go to sleep. This means that your UI can't be updated during that time.

On the other hand, `await` means, there is some code here that will tell you when its done. Until its done, go outside and do something else (like update the UI). `Task.Delay(500)` means, in 500ms time, tell someone that you are "done".

The difference therefore is that during those 500ms, this solution will allow your UI thread to do all its housekeeping stuff, like update the screen, respond to the mouse etc etc, whilst your code has the very important UI thread go on holiday (leaving your UI closed to business).

Comment: Surely you mean to use Task.Delay(500) instead of Task.Wait(500)? Even so, I don't believe this will work.

Comment: You should explain your code to OP.  You've written quite a bit in the comments about keeping things simple for OP, yet you've put zero effort here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks to Aron, I had to make the method into an async method to be able to use await - and now it works! I can 'wait' whilst updating my UI. Here's the edited code:

```
    async void move(int floor)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan duration;
        while (floor > elevator.currentFloor)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            elevator.currentFloor++;
            changeStatus(elevator);
            currentFloorLbl.Text = "Current Floor: " + elevator.currentFloor;
            duration = DateTime.Now - now;
            timeLbl.Text = "Time elapsed: " + duration.TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + "ms";
        }
```